# ul list gets hidden under a div

Tags: html, css, html-lists, z-index

I've been having this issue in different places where I have a ul list and Im trying to add it on top of a div (image, or a background) but the list does not appear on top. I wonder if it gets sent in the back..i even added z-index

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj1ed7so/2/)

CSS

```
.toolbar p{ text-align: right; padding: 10px 180px 0 0; color: #fff; font-size: 26px; z-index: 1; }
.toolbar { width: auto; height: 50px; background-color:  #cc1e2c; z-index: 1;}
.social-icons { z-index: 2;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col_full toolbar"> 
            <p>CALL NOW: +1 555.555.1234</p>
            <ul class="social-icons">
                <li> <a href="graphics/twitter_icon.jpg" target="_blank"> </a></li>
                <li> <a href="graphics/instagram_icon.jpg" target="_blank"> </a></li>
                <li> <a href="graphics/facebook_icon.jpg" target="_blank"> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: [Like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/kj1ed7so/3/)

Comment: `z-index` only works on an element that _has position_. Try adding `position: relative`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I did @KevinBoucher, still the same

Comment: Stacking context can be complicated. That article should provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't seeing anything is because you posted links, without any content. If you added words, the list would appear:

```
<div class="col_full toolbar"> 
            <p>CALL NOW: +1 555.555.1234</p>
            <ul class="social-icons">
                <li> <a href="graphics/twitter_icon.jpg" target="_blank">Twitter </a></li>
                <li> <a href="graphics/instagram_icon.jpg" target="_blank"> Instagram</a></li>
                <li> <a href="graphics/facebook_icon.jpg" target="_blank"> Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

On this example I made the height bigger so you could see that the links are in fact on top.

If you want to see the images, you need to use the image tag like so:

```
<li> <a href="path/to/twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="path/to/your/twitter_image.jpg"/> </a></li>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj1ed7so/5/)

Comment: I'm not seeing the images in your fiddle.

Comment: @j08691 the images aren't included in the fiddle. the link you provided doesn't work, thus there are no images to insert.

Comment: The link I provided? What link?

Comment: @j08691, I'm sorry the URL/path to the images that were in your fiddle